# How to remove duplicates rows by same values in different order in dataframe by pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to remove the duplicates in the df? df only has 1 column. In this case "60,25" and "25,60" is a pair of duplicated rows. The output should be the new df. For each pair of duplicated row, the kept row in format "A,B" where A < B, the removed row should be the one A>B. In this case, "25,60" and "80,123" should be kept. For unique row, it should stay whatever it is.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, using `get_dummies` with `duplicated`

```
df[~df.A.str.get_dummies(sep=',').duplicated()]
Out[956]: 
       A
0    A,C
1    A,B
4  X,Y,Z
```

Data input

```
df
Out[957]: 
       A
0    A,C
1    A,B
2    C,A
3    B,A
4  X,Y,Z
5  Z,Y,X
```

Update op change the question totally to different question

```
newdf=df.A.str.get_dummies(sep=',')
newdf[~newdf.duplicated()].dot(newdf.columns+',').str[:-1]
Out[976]: 
0     25,60
1    123,37
dtype: object
```

Comment: I updated my question. It needs to remove the duplicated by a certain constrain. Would you please update your solution accordingly? Thanks!

Comment: @yoyoyo to be honest , I do not like op change the question , this is two different questions

Comment: Thanks Wen. However the logic is for example I have 25,60 60,25 137,80 80,137. it's in the format of "A,B",and I need to make sure A<B are kept, those A>B duplicated rows are removed. Your code kept 137,80 instead of 80,137

Comment: @yoyoyo my test data 137,80  is unique , so that is why I did not change it

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I mean in my question the "123,80" and "80,123" is a pair of duplicated rows, "25,60" and "60,25" is a pair of duplicated rows, but with your above solution "123,80" and "25,60" was kept, however I need to make A<B for the kept duplicated rows, so "123,80" is incorrect here. for the unique row it should stay whatever it is, regardless A>B or A<B

Answer (score 1):

I'd do a combination of things.

1. Use `pandas.Series.str.split` to split by commas
2. Use `apply(frozenset)` to get a hashable set such that I can use `duplicated`
3. Use `pandas.Series.duplicated` with `keep='last'`

---

```
df[~df.A.str.split(',').apply(frozenset).duplicated(keep='last')]

        A
1  123,17
3  80,123
4   25,60
5   25,42
```

#### Addressing comments

```
df.A.apply(
    lambda x: tuple(sorted(map(int, x.split(','))))
).drop_duplicates().apply(
    lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x))
)

0     25,60
1    17,123
2    80,123
5     25,42
Name: A, dtype: object
```

---

### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A='60,25 123,17 123,80 80,123 25,60 25,42'.split()
))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the 'keep='last' intended to remove 1st duplicated row and keep 2nd row? Mine actual data has thousand rows. For some duplicated rows, I need to keep the 1st item and for others I need to keep the 2nd. Always keep whose 1st number < 2nd number. So does your code work this way?

Comment: Your data seemed to keep the last row.  `keep='last'` will ensure that the last observation will not be marked as a dup.

Comment: The sample data was made up. I just realized I should adjust the order of 60,25 and 25,60. So 25,60 is the top row and 60,25 at the bottom. How to achieve the same goal if in this order?

Comment: Remove the `keep='last'` parameter.  You'd want `keep='first'` but that is the default and so you don't need to specify it.

Comment: I mean for example I have 25,60  60,25  137,80  80,137 so I want to keep 1st and 4th item. I don't think keep='first' can work out.

Comment: What is the logic that defines keeping the first and fourth items?  Is it sorted?

Comment: for example I have 25,60 60,25 137,80 80,137. it's in the format of "A,B",and I need to make sure A<B are kept, those A>B duplicated rows are removed.

Comment: Try: `df.loc[df.A.str.split(',').apply(tuple).sort_values().apply(frozenset).drop_duplicates().index]`

Comment: If the original df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A='25,60 123,17 123,80 80,123 60,25 25,42'.split()
)), the new df with your above code it kept 123,80 instead of 80,123

Comment: I neglected to sort by integer values.  See if my update helps.

Comment: still kept 123,80 instead of 80,123

Comment: I see, you want the final thing sorted.  One second.

Comment: Thanks  @piRSquared. If possible I want to the new df, each row in the format "A,B" can be grouped by A. so it will be like "25,60" "25,42" "123,17" "80,123". Is there a way to make it happen without split-group by-concatenate?

Comment: You'll have to edit your question or ask a new one where you are more explicit about what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I may ask another question later for the grouping. This one question is intend to serve the purpose of remove duplicated rows.

Comment: "123,17" is unique and shouldn't get sorted. I updated my question now it's more clear I think. Please test your code with the example in my question. I really appreciate your help and time!